# How to make permanent changes to a website's CSS from within the browser?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

If I am trying to edit some `CSS` in a huge project using the *built-in* *developer tools* in Firefox (which is accessed by right click and then selecting *Inspect Element*), is there a way to make those changes permanent?

Actually there is a big number of style sheets and and I could not locate this one property in them? I just could not find the file which contains this property, so I want to make permanent changes to the CSS from within the browser. Is there a way?

---

EDIT:-
[image]

Comment: I am not sure about Fire Fox but in Chrome you can map your local CSS files in DevTools so that when you make changes they are saved to your actual CSS files. Do you use Chrome?? If so ill post an answer with the steps needed.

Comment: Although I haven't tried it myself yet, according to this page it seems entirely possible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Style_Editor

Comment: The only way to make changes permanent is to update a file or database on a server. Otherwise everything is local and subject to change.

Comment: Not the solution you want, but if you're making the changes in IE11, it will provide color tips on the side to indicate which properties you've changed, so once you have the effect you need, you can write all of those to your CSS file manually.

Comment: Have you been searching manually through the style sheets? You might have a better time grep'ing them for the keyword you are looking for.

Comment: [Chrome's Workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces) is what @GifCo is referring to, and should help with both finding properties and persisiting them.

Comment: @GifCo Oh yes totally I can use Chrome. Please tell me the process if it is simple, because I am a newb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set up in Chrome first you have to add your project file to a "Workspace", Go into dev tools Ctrl+Shift+I then click on the settings gear and on the left yoou should see Workspace.

After you have added your Project folder into a workspace close out of options and click on the "Sources" tab (still in dev tools)

Now load up your index.html from your LocalHost like you normally would. In the sources panel you should see the currently loaded page and its resources. Right click on your .css file and click "Map To File System Resource" it will bring up a search box where you can search for the corresponding .css file from your actual project folder (that is now part of a workspace in Chrome). Once you make the link Chrome is smart enough to link up any other CSS and HTML files that are in your Project Folder.

Now you can make changes in the Elements tab in Chrome Dev Tools and they changes will persist. Also in the ELements tab it will show you what css file and what line any given Style is originating from!

The best thing about this is if you use Sass or Less then it will map your Scss files back to the CSS styles being processed in Chrome. (please note if using Sass and Less you have to have CSS source maps turned on)

Comment: `"Right click on your .css file and click "Map To File System Resource"` This is the problem. i don't know what css file it is.

Comment: yes but it doesnt matter as once you map one CSS file Chrome will then map every CSS file in the project folder that you added to the Workspace

Comment: Hey I found the file here in the workspace. But when I click it and click "Map to File System Resource", a box appears with no `search` button or something, and pressing enter does not do anything. I added a screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do this by hand, there is a plugin for FF called Stylish that allows you to define rules-based style tweaks.

---

EDIT

I mention this only because it allows you to publish a set of style changes that any Firefox client can pick up and install to a specific installation. Since one can't "permanently" change the contents of remote style information, the only solution is to manipulate it on a semi-permanent basis on each user-agent that needs the changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Web Developer Toolbar for this matter. By going to CSS menu and then to 'Edit CSS' where you can edit and save your changes. Il also provides tools for identify which files are relevant and modify them manually. Also you may try Firebug extension where you can do similar things.
Links to both here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/web-developer/

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/

If you have installed Firebug you could install cssUpdater to simplify the process of saving changes.

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cssupdater/

Comment: Hi, I looked into `Edit CSS` but it is a mess of a massive number of files. I just don't know where the one line I want to edit is.

Comment: Use cssUpdater with Firebug to simplify the process of saving those files. You can avoid previous definitions and force one by adding !important to the css definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at userContent.css:

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#usercss